# Fill two DataTable in single DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset

I have single `DataSet.xsd` file and in this i have two `DataTable` one is `Bill` and another is `BillInfo` now, i am fill writing this code

```
string qry = "Select * from BillInfo where [BillNumber]='" +txtbill.Text + "' and [Session]='"+CLS.ses+"'";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = bm.returnDataAdaptor(qry);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds1);
        DataSets.Bill ds = new DataSets.Bill();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable Dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("BillInfo");
        dt.Columns.Add("BillNumber", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("City", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Mobile", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("TotalAmount", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Packing", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Tax", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Transport", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Additional", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("PaybleAmount", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Session", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Date1", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Naration", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("AmountWord", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Status", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Balance", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

        for (int i = 0; i < Dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
            r["BillNumber"] = Dt1.Rows[i][0];
            r["CustomerName"] = Dt1.Rows[i][1];
            r["City"] = Dt1.Rows[i][2];
            r["Mobile"] = Dt1.Rows[i][3];
            r["TotalAmount"] = Dt1.Rows[i][4];
            r["Packing"] = Dt1.Rows[i][5];
            r["Tax"] = Dt1.Rows[i][6];
            r["Transport"] = Dt1.Rows[i][7];
            r["Additional"] = Dt1.Rows[i][8];
            r["PaybleAmount"] = Dt1.Rows[i][9];
            r["Session"] = Dt1.Rows[i][10];
            r["Date1"] = Dt1.Rows[i][11];
            r["Naration"] = Dt1.Rows[i][12];
            r["AmountWord"] = Dt1.Rows[i][13];
            r["Status"] = Dt1.Rows[i][14];
            r["Balance"] = Dt1.Rows[i][15];
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        string qry1 = "Select * from BillDetails where [BillNumber]='" + txtbill.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataAdapter da1 = bm.returnDataAdaptor(qry1);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds2);
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable Dt2 = ds2.Tables[0];
        DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables.Add("Bill");
        dt2.Columns.Add("BillNumber", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("ProductCode", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("ProductName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("productSize", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("ProductQuantity", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("ProductWeight", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("Unit", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("ProductPrice", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("Amount", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt2.Columns.Add("Date1", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
        for (int i = 0; i < Dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
            r["BillNumber"] = Dt2.Rows[i][0];
            r["ProductCode"] = Dt2.Rows[i][1];
            r["ProductName"] = Dt2.Rows[i][2];
            r["productSize"] = Dt2.Rows[i][3];
            r["ProductQuantity"] = Dt2.Rows[i][4];
            r["ProductWeight"] = Dt2.Rows[i][5];
            r["Unit"] = Dt2.Rows[i][6];
            r["ProductPrice"] = Dt2.Rows[i][7];
            r["Amount"] = Dt2.Rows[i][8];
            r["Date1"] = Dt2.Rows[i][9];
            dt2.Rows.Add(r);
        }
```

but at the `r["ProductCode"] = Dt2.Rows[i][1];` it is showing an exception. That is `Column 'ProductCode' does not belong to table BillInfo.` Please solve my error.

Comment: Column 'ProductCode' does not belong to table BillInfo.

Comment: @Rajneesh i have mention in question.

Comment: You are open for sql-injection when you use textboxes as input for your sql query. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Ok @TimSchmelter i will surely used parameterized query.

Comment: @Ankur `bm.returnDataAdaptor(qry);` at this line what refer to **bm** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
```

with

```
DataRow r = dt2.NewRow();
```

You have simply used the wrong table which has no column `ProductCode`. It must be "Bill" instead of "BillInfo".

Apart from that:

**You are open for sql-injection when you use textboxes as input for your sql query. Use parameters instead.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very clear `Column 'ProductCode' does not belong to table BillInfo` instead I can see Column 'ProductCode' is in `BillDetails`.